# while listar resultado de 4 em 4 dentro de div

Tags: php

Pessoal como faço para lista o resultado de uma consulta sql de forma que de 4 em 4 linha fiquem dentro de uma div.

Ex. resultado esperado:

```
<div class="row">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <span>5</span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>7</span>
    <span>8</span>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <span>9</span>
    <span>10</span>
</div>
```

Teste:

```
$count = 0;
while ($count <= 10) {
    if ($count % 4) {
        echo '<div class="row"><span>'.$count.'</span></div>';
    }

    $count++;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que falta é isolar as divs `.row` dos elementos `<span>` ou seja se span aparece independente de ser do `% 4` então ele nem deveria estar dentro do `while` e o `% 4` deve sempre ser comparado a 1 ou 0 (como sugestão do @Bacco pra simplificar começamos compararemos com o `% 4` zero):

```
<?php
$count = 0;

echo '<div class="row">', PHP_EOL;

while ($count <= 10) {
    if ($count > 0 && $count % 4 === 0) {//A cada quatro deve fechar o .row e abrir novamente
        echo '</div>', PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL, '<div class="row">', PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo '<span>', $count, '</span>', PHP_EOL;

    $count++;
}

echo '</div>';
```

Uma coisa importante é que o seu código não está gerando 10 itens, mas sim 11, pois ele começa no zero, então se o incremento começasse do 1 o código seria mais simples, pois a quantidade seria 10, será necessário verificar se é maior que 1:

```
<?php
$count = 1;

echo '<div class="row">', PHP_EOL;

while ($count <= 10) {
    if ($count > 1 && $count % 4 === 1) {//A cada quatro deve fechar o .row e abrir novamente
        echo '</div>', PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL, '<div class="row">', PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo '<span>', $count, '</span>', PHP_EOL;

    $count++;
}

echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Cara ficou muito bom, vlw @GuilhermeNascimento

Answer (score 7):

Esta versão tem lógica similar à tentativa do autor e a resposta do @Guilherme, usando o `%`. A diferença é que o cálculo do módulo foi feito em 2 linhas separadas, para evitar a repetição dos `echo`s da `div`:

```
$count = 10;
$group = 4;

for ( $i = 1; $i <= $count; ++$i ) {
    if ( ( $i - 1 ) % $group == 0 ) echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<span>'.$i.'</span>';
    if ( $i == $count || $i % $group == 0 ) echo '</div>';
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/M50w6x)**.

Segue uma alternativa com dois *loops*, que pode ser adaptada para cenarios mais complexos:

```
    $count = 10;
    $group = 4;

    for ( $i = 1; $i <= $count; $i += $group ) {
        echo '<div class="row">';
        for ( $j = 0; $j < $group && $j + $i <= $count ; $j++ ) {
            echo '<span>'.($j + $i).'</span>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/8QeuVh)**.

Comment: Como experiência, fiz uma versão de uma linha só. Na prática, isso não deve ser feito pra não ficar ilegível na hora de dar manutenção.  http://ideone.com/xlbAAc

Answer (score 0):

Fiz dessa forma:

```
    $count = 0;
    while ($count <= 10) {
        if ($count % 4) { 
            echo '<span>' . $count . '</span>';
        } else {
            if($count === 0 ){
            echo '<div class="row">';
            echo '<span>' . $count . '</span>';
            } else {
                 echo '</div>';
                 echo '<div class="row">';
                 echo '<span>' . $count . '</span>';
            }

        }
        if($count === 10){
            echo '</div>';
        }

        $count++;
    }
```